# ODP.NET can't read data from data reader

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, odp.net

I am new to Oracle and trying to get data from a Oracle DB. Following is my code. No error is showing in the console. But in the code will not enter inside the while loop. As I am new to this somebody please help me to solve this issue ?

```
public void Login()
        {
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;

                try
                {
                    LogManager.Info("inside login");
                    connection.Open();
                    OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;

                    string sql = "select ID from APRV_EMPLOYEE where USERNAME = :username ";
                    LogManager.Info("sql" + sql);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.BindByName = true;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(":username", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = "admin";
                    IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    LogManager.Info("Inside DatabaseManager::hasrows");
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        LogManager.Info("Inside DatabaseManager::read" + reader.GetString(1));
                        LogManager.Info("Inside DatabaseManager::read2" + reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")));

                    }

                    reader.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogManager.Error("Inside DatabaseManager::Login " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to try `cmd.Parameters.Add("username", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = "admin";`, I can never remember if the `:` is supposed to be there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleParameterClass.htm), here is how it should work

```
string sql = "select ID from APRV_EMPLOYEE where USERNAME = :1 ";
LogManager.Info("sql" + sql);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = sql;
// cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add("username", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = "admin";
IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: even "SELECT id from APRV_EMPLOYEE" always returing raeder.HasRows false even there is an entry in Database.. Please help ..

Comment: In that case, are you connecting to the same database (in code as compared to the query editor, where you can see the records)?

Comment: Thanks.. When I tried the query in Oracle SQL developer and run the query, it showing the row well. Connecting the same database

Comment: @ramesh Are you logging in using the same credentials so that you don't end up in a separate default tablespace?

Comment: @ramesh: So, what exactly was the reason? If Joachim's answer helped you, dont accept this as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @shahkalpesh ... exactly I got the answer from your point. I didn't committed the changes in Oracle SQL Developer. Thats why I was getting null from code end and getting records from SQL Developer. So I crosschecked your point ( Sec comment ) and got my problem solved. Thanks